# Connect to SQL Server with Azure AD MFA Authentication from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database, azure

Previously I was able to connect to a server with Windows authentication as shown in the code below

However, my company changed authentication to only allow Azure Active Directory with MFA

I can connect to DB with SQL Server Management Studio, but not from PHP.

I realize that I won't be able to automate the MFA completely, because it needs to authenticate through my phone, but I might not need to, because as long as the SQL Management Studio is running in the background, I just need to do an MFA authentication step once.

I'd like to know:

1. Is it possible to auth with the Azure AD with MFA through PHP? If yes, please show in code
2. Is it possible to integrate SQL Management Studio with PHP so that I can make SQL queries to it from PHP while it's already logged in to the database?
3. Maybe I can log into database from SQL Management Studio and run it in the background, while PHP executes queries without requiring MFA?

   ```
    <?php  
        $serverName = "******.database.windows.net";  
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"********"); 
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
        if( $conn === false )  
        {  
            echo "Unable to connect.</br>";  
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
        }
        $tsql = "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), SUSER_SNAME())";  
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  
        if( $stmt === false )  
        {  
            echo "Error in executing query.</br>";  
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
        }  
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);  
        echo "User login: ".$row[0]."</br>";  

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
        sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
    ?>
   ```

[image]

Comment: *"Is it possible to integrate SQL Management Studio with PHP"* no. SSMS is an IDE-Like application, not a library you can call to connect to a database engine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [ODBC driver to connect with AAD Auth](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16), with ActiveDirectoryPassword or ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal.

If your org requires an MFA login, then ActiveDirectoryPassword probably won't work.